# What is the recommended mechanism for initializing a redis database for a node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I am new to **node.js**, and am not yet familiar with the ecosystem around it.

I have a one-page **Express** app that caches some data in **redis** and I would like to add a few configuration settings to the **redis** db. Thus far I have been simply using **redis-cli** to manually set the necessary keys. I would prefer to somehow have **npm** run a script (or something), so that deploying the app on a server is as simple as possible.

What is the recommended mechanism for initializing a **redis** database for a **node.js** app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `redis` module on npm you could easily use `mset()` to set multiple keys in one go. Example:

```
var redis  = require('redis'),
    client = redis.createClient();

var kv = [
  'key1', 'value1',
  'key2', 2,
  'key3', 'value3'
];
client.mset(kv, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // end the connection gracefully if
  // you don't need to access redis anymore
  client.quit();
});
```